# How to assess the association between categorical/ordinal variables?

Tags: correlation

I'd like to see if there is a correlation between a biomarker (independent variable), indicated as positive (1) or negative (0), and the number of symptoms of each subject, stated as 1,2,3 or 4 symptoms. The distribution is not normal. Which test can I use?

Comment: Hi Holly and welcome to CV. We'll need a bit more information to help, we'll try and ask relevant questions to get to it. Is it specifically correlation you need? Or do you more generally mean that you need to demonstrate an association between the biomarker and the number of symptoms? Is there at most 4 symptoms and do you have any symptom free subjects?

Comment: Something like Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney test?

Comment: Thank you. I need to demonstrate a general association. The most is 4 symptoms and at least 1. Yes, I thought about MW test but I'm not sure it is the most convenient.

Comment: First, is your second variable _counts_ (1,2,3..., number of symptoms)? If yes then it isn't _ordinal_ variable, rather, it is ratio type. Second, your first variable is binary, not just categorical. You should add tag `binary-data`.

Comment: Maybe ease up on the technical terminology for the moment. In plain English: I think you want to know whether the biomarker is somehow related to the number of symptoms. Also you should be looking for the best test, not the 'most convenient' one. // My answer offers sort of a cafeteria of choices for you to think about. Pick one, explain your choice, and maybe someone can help you implement it--or nudge you in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Absent an answer to @ReneBT's question, I will speculate that subjects
are patients with at least one symptom, and that the number of symptoms
can be 1, 2, 3, or 4. If you have 60 patients who are Pos for the marker
and 100 who are Neg, then your counts $X_{ij}$ might be similar to those in the matrix
below, where the respective columns are Pos and Neg, and the rows give
the number of symptoms.

```
MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8   29
[2,]   13   32
[3,]   27   18
[4,]   22   21
```

**Chi-squared test of independence.** A standard chi-squared test of the independence of rows and columns
in R gives results as follows:

```
rslt = chisq.test(MAT);  rslt

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 17, df = 3, p-value = 0.0007068
```

So the null hypothesis of independence is rejected. The expected cell
frequencies $E_{ij}$ are:

```
  rslt$exp
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 15.23529 21.76471
[2,] 18.52941 26.47059
[3,] 18.52941 26.47059
[4,] 17.70588 25.29412
```

The following are Pearson residuals  $(X_{ij} - E_{ij})/\sqrt{E_{ij}}.$
Roughly, their message is that Pos subjects tend to have proportionately higher numbers of symptoms than Neg ones.

```
rslt$resi
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -1.853663  1.5508857
[2,] -1.284541  1.0747245
[3,]  1.967808 -1.6463864
[4,]  1.020505 -0.8538158
```

The squares of the Pearson residuals are the 'contributions' of each cell
of the $4 \times 2$ table to the chi-squared statistic, reported in the 
initial results to be 17.

```
sum(rslt$resi^2)
[1] 16.99968
```

**Other possible tests.** The test above treats the number of symptoms as a nominal categorical variable.
Various other tests could treat them as ordinal categorical variables, or
as numerical. Recognizing them as numerical would focus directly on the larger
numbers of symptoms in Pos patients rather than on the association of categorical variables.

***Welch t test.*** While the fake data presented here are clearly not normal, t tests with as many
patients as here could be defended on the basis of the robustness of t tests
to non-normal data (absent extreme outliers). A Welch separate variances t test  on the numbers of symptoms reported by 60 Pos and 100 Neg patients shows
a highly significant difference between the two groups in the average number of symptoms.

```
t.test(pos, neg)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  pos and neg
t = 3.2586, df = 128.76, p-value = 0.001432
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2252111 0.9214556
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2.883333  2.310000
```

***2-sample Wilcoxon test.*** Ignoring that it is difficult to imagine there is a simple
'location shift' in the distribution of symptoms from Neg to Pos and also hoping for a satisfactory correction for the ties in the data, many statisticians (presumably @user2974951 among them) would feel comfortable doing a Wilcoxon rank sum test, which also shows a highly significant difference.

```
wilcox.test(pos, neg)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  pos and neg
W = 3860, p-value = 0.001736
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

***Permutation test.*** A permutation test using the Welch t statistic as metric (but not assuming it has a t distribution) would not be subject to the criticisms of Welch t and Wilcoxon SR tests; it gives P-value about 0.002.

```
set.seed(1016)
pos = sample(1:4, 60, rep=T, prob=c(.1, .2, .3, .4))
neg = sample(1:4, 100, rep=T, prob=c(.3, .3, .2, .2))

t.obs = t.test(pos, neg)$stat
all = c(pos, neg);  gp = c(rep(1,60),rep(2,100))
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(all ~ sample(gp))$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.00171
```

*Note:* The first three lines of the R code above were used to simulate the
fake data used throughout.